# What can MFI enable?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, sms, mfi

I'm trying to determine what functionality I can add to a BT accessory by paying for the MFI authentication coprocessor.  For example, could I...

A. Pass location data to the accessory?
B. Push incoming SMS messages to the accessory?
C. Launch my app on the phone from the accessory?

Answer (score 6):

As Dennis mentioned, all information regarding the MFi program is covered under a VERY water tight NDA.  However, what can be said is that all devices that connect to the iPad through Bluetooth or the docking connector port are accessed through the External Accessory framework.  Documentation on the External Accessory framework is easily accessibly from Apple's documentation pages and can also be easily googled.

Communication with devices through the External Accessory framework is fairly simple once you've established a connection with a device.  In short, the process is to find the desired connected accessory from an array of devices, establish a connection session and the session object contains a input and output stream.  Data by creating a delegate that with the device and finally, monitor the associated input and output streams which you use to communicate with the device.

Again, the majority of the information associated with MFi is tightly sealed.  However, as far as connecting to devices (that you have the right to connect to) is simple, well documented and is easily searchable since the framework is part of the standard, iOS library.

One other note on Bluetooth.  There is also a Core Bluetooth framework that is available with iOS 5.0 and up.  This is a much simpler framework that you can use to discover and auto pair with Bluetooth Low-Energy devices (which are part of the new Bluetooth 4.0 spec.)

If you are planning on making an iPad application or desire to have a fairly high level of backwards compatibility with earlier iOS devices, I wouldn't recommend using the new CoreBluetooth framework.  The reason is because only the iPhone 4S and  the soon to be released "New iPad" have the necessary Bluetooth chipset to connect with Bluetooth LE devices.

Comment: Learn about the External Accessory Framework [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009502).

Answer (score 1):

All Mfi information is under NDA. 
It dosent cost anything to sign up and get access to the information , you can do it here.
https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/